Special case of L’Hopital for functions differentiable at a single point
I was given the following homework problem:
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
If $f(x)=g(x)=0$ and $g'(x) \neq 0$, show that
$$
\lim_{t \to x} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.
$$
We have already proven L’Hopital and have covered theorems concerning limits in the context of “Principles of Mathematical Analysis”, 3rd edition, by Walter Rudin.
The conditions for indeterminacy, non-zero derivative, and existence of quotient do appear to hold, but
I am worried that since there is no continuity condition on $f,g$ on a neighborhood of $x$ the question could be flawed, as L’Hopital wouldn’t hold. Furthermore, if L’Hopital does hold, what guarantees $$\lim_{t \to x} \frac{f’(t)}{g’(t)}= \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} ?$$

Where does this problem come from?  Do you know the proof of L'Hostpital?  Note that $f$ and $g$ are continuous (they are differentiable, and you should know something about the relationship between continuity and differentiability), but that isn't quite the interesting subtlety here.

$f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$ but the conditions require a neighborhood around $x$

So this is exercise 5.7 on page 114 of Rudin?  If so, I would suggest that you look at theorems 5.12 and 5.13---look at the proofs, too.  I do not think that you should be thinking of applying L'Hospital in this case.  Rather, you should think about the proof techniques used there, and how you can apply them to this problem.

This should be possible to prove with epsilon-delta definitions.

thanks! Is there a reason this is closed now? is there still context missing?

no, because it's a duplicate. See the two links
